# iOS InterfaceBuilder: SearchBar wont show when y position is changed

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a UITableView with a search bar inside a UIview. I changed the Y position so that the UITableView is moved down, but when I load the app the y position seems to be reset and is moved up. How do I fix this?

UITableView/SearchBar moved down in UIView:

[image: UITableView with search bar]

UITableView/SearchBar after app loads:

[image: UITableView after app is loaded]

Comment: you may have to programmatically force the table view to shift down

Comment: also this could possibly due to the fact that you have no data in the tableview so it is hiding the header?

Comment: ok, I'll try to programmatically move it down. Also, will load some data to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid the problem of the table view covering the search bar entirely by putting it in the `tableHeaderView` property of the the tableview rather than the enclosing `UIView` - I think this is a fairly standard way of doing it:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

The presence or absence of data in the tableview shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Go it working:

```
_recipeList = [[RecipeViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

//Create a frame for the current table view controller
CGRect frame = _recipeList.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = 57;
_recipeList.view.frame = frame;

[self.view addSubview:_recipeList.view];
```